# Import only a class static method

Tags: python, inheritance, import

I have the following decorator in a base class:

```
class BaseTests(TestCase):
    @staticmethod
    def check_time(self, fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def test_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            # do checks ...
        return test_wrapper
```

And the following class inheriting from BaseTests:

```
from path.base_posting import BaseTests
from path.base_posting.BaseTests import check_time  # THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK!

class SpecificTest(BaseTests):

    @check_time # use the decorator
    def test_post(self):
        # do testing ...
```

I would like to use the decorator in SpecificTest as above, without having to use BaseTests.check_time, because in the original code they have long names, and I have to use it in many places. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I decided to make check_time an independent function in BaseTests file, and simply import

```
from path.base_posting import BaseTests, check_time
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simply put

```
check_time = BaseTests.check_time
```

in your second module:

---

```
from module_paths.base_posting import BaseTests
check_time = BaseTests.check_time

class SpecificTest(BaseTests):

    @check_time # use the decorator
    def test_post(self):
        # do testing ...
```

---

You may also want to reconsider making `check_time` a staticmethod, since it appears your use case employs it more as a stand-alone function than as a staticmethod.

Comment: nice, thanks. I was looking for a solution which imports the method directly, but your suggestion works as well.