# How to import datetime.now so I can call it with just now()?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I want to be able to call `datetime.now()` in my program.

- `import datetime` requires me to do `datetime.datetime.now()`
- `from datetime import datetime` still requires me to do `datetime.now()`
- `from datetime.datetime import now` doesn't compile

Is there a way to import it so that I don't have to specify the parent classes? Ie. I want to be able to do `t = now()` as opposed to `t = datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't import `datetime.datetime.now` directly because `datetime` is **not a module**, it is actually a class, and `now` is a classmethod. [Here is a similar question regarding import static methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603541/import-only-a-class-static-method)

Here is a minimal working code to be able to do what you need.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now
```

Answer (score 1):

By creating a function?

```
import datetime

def now():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

print now()
```

Comment: this is the only answer so far that actually addresses the question.

Comment: How did you decide that this is the best answer? I see more than one good answers here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Closest thing you can do is something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

t = dt.now()
```

the first "datetime" is a module. This module contains a class "datetime". This class has a method "now()"

Edit: Sebastien D is a "solution" to your particular question, but i would strongly advise against using something like that in your projects.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use it this way:

```
from datetime import datetime


t = datetime.now()
newdate = datetime.strftime(t, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(t)
# result: 2018-01-25 19:30:04.829242

print("Formatted Date: " + str(newdate))
# Formatted Date: 25/01/2018 19:30:04
```

Answer (score -1):

Great question. Next time try and show some more code, and your error message so we can answer your question better. Anyway, try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.now()
print(t)
```

Or, if that's not what you are looking for, then try this:

```
import datetime

mydate = datetime.date(1943,3, 13)
print(mydate.strftime("%A"))
```