# Python: when is it necessary to prefix a module name?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm literally days-new to Python programming after years of `C++` and `C` programming, and am trying to get a feel for the grammar.

In the following very-beginner code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

print( datetime.now() )
# print( now() ) # NameError: name 'now' is not defined

print( date(2005, 2, 27) )
# print( datetime.date(2005, 2, 27) ) # TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

...**why is it necessary to scope `now()` in `datetime` but apparently incorrect to do so with `date(...)`**?

The learning material I'm referencing said the two `import statements` mean I'm "*importing the date and datetime classes from the datetime standard module.*" Possibly biased from my `C++` background, I'm equating `module` with `namespace` and would have thought this meant (1) you'd need to explicitly scope functions and classes with the module they came from (like `std::sort()`), or (2) not need explicit scoping because the `from/import` clause is akin to `CC++`'s `using` clause. So the grammar of the above looks odd to me because it looks like *I'm using two "things" that come from the datetime "namespace," and I must scope  one thing but not the other*.

FWIW, I use `vim` as my editor - I wonder: would something about this have been more transparent with a a graphical/autosuggest-enabled editor?

To any answerers, I'd be grateful if you could explain how an experienced Python programmer would go about finding out the answer to a question like this. What I mean is: in `C`/`C++`, I'd look up whatever `.h` I `#include` to find out what's what - how do you go about "looking up" the datetime "module"?

Comment: The basic difference is that `date` is a class, therefore you can import it but `now` is a static method of `datetime` class. `date(2005, 2, 27)` is analogous to `new date(2005, 2, 27)` in Java.

Comment: The general answer is "when the thing you want to refer to is inside the module you imported". You imported `date` so you can use it directly. You did not import `now` but you did import `datetime` which contains this function.

Comment: The `datetime` module *is* a bit of a twisty maze. Most other modules do not have a class with the same name as the module, which is definitely confusing.

Comment: @tripleee  Ooh, duh: I think I get it: there is actually a `datetime` _class_ in the `datetime` _module_ - is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, exactly -- sorry for using the incorrect terminology earlier (updated my comment already).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So your datetime.now() is actually datetime.datetime.now().

Comment: Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454014/how-to-import-datetime-now-so-i-can-call-it-with-just-now

Comment: Yep. There is actually a `class datetime(date):` line in `datetime.py`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L1558

Comment: @Selcuk So `datetime.now()` is invoking a static function from the `datetime` _class_ and is not a non-member function of the `datetime` _module_, right?

Comment: @StoneThrow You are right. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to write `datetime.now()` because you have only imported `datetime.datetime` class, not the whole `datetime` module. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct - you don't need to scope! This is a slightly confusing situation because the `datetime` module has a class which is also called `datetime`.

So what's happening in each of these:

`print(datetime.now())`  # Call the `now()` class method of the `datetime` class and print its output
`print(now())`  # now() is not defined in the namespace, hence the error
`print(date(2005, 2, 27))`  # Instantiate a `date` object and print its representation
`print(datetime.date(2005, 2, 27))`  # This is trying to call the `date()` method of the `datetime` class, which doesn't exist, hence the error.

With the last case, if you had just done `import datetime`, the whole `datetime` *module* would have been imported. In that case, you can instantiate a `date` class object by doing datetime.date(2005, 2, 27).

Hope that makes a tiny bit of sense!

Comment: So the pattern I'm seeing is: `import datetime` imports the whole datetime "namespace" but you are not implicitly "using" the namespace, i.e. you need to scope references to datetime objects with `datetime.`, e.g. `datetime.date(...)`. But `from datetime import x` means you are implicitly "using" the namespace, because you can reference datetime objects without the `datetime.` scope, e.g. `date(...)`.

Comment: Exactly StoneThrow with one difference, `from MODULE import OBJECT` is not equivalent to including and using in C++ as it only imports `MODULE.OBJECT`, you can't use any other object from that module. I think it is obvious but I'll write it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The importing in python ist simple. When you import

```
from datetime import datetime
```

then you have from modul datetime only import the class / function datetime. (In this case a class). Your interpreter don't know the function "now" but you can access to it when you take the loop over that what you imported.

```
datetime.now()
```

after your second import

```
from datetime import date
```

your compiler knows the classes date and datetime. When you try

```
print( datetime.date(2005, 2, 27) )
```

then it is not that what you expect. You try to call from class datetime the function date which have other parameters as the class date from modul datetime. 
The problem with the modul datetime is that it contains a class with datetime so it is a little bit confusing.